# Is while(1) really infinite?

Tags: c, loops

I have this program:

```
int main(){
    while(1) printf("Hi\n");
}
```

Is that really repeating forever? If i put the `while(1)`, without `printf`, will be the same number of repetition? If it not forever, when the stack overflow? That program:

```
int main(){
    loop:;
    printf("Hi\n");
    goto loop;
}
```

is the same as the first? If not what the differences?

Comment: It's repeating at least as long as 1 remains equal to 1.

Comment: Without the `printf`, I think you have undefined behaviour.

Comment: Why do you think the stack would ever overflow? That makes no sense!

Comment: @KerrekSB That would be C++. In C it is defined I think. That is some weirdness right there

Comment: @Jon: actually, it repeats as long as 1 keeps being different than zero, which puts us in an even safer place.

Comment: I did not know if the while(1) repeat forever, so if it was not forever, only stack overflow or signal could close the program...

Comment: @Chichila Yes, a stack overflow would cause the program to exit. However, a stack overflow isn't just some weird thing that happens sometimes out of the blue, nor something that can be (easily) triggered by some user or process external to the program, like a signal can. If your code isn't doing anything that would *cause* the stack to overflow, it's not going to just spontaneously overflow. In particular, if your program is just sitting there spinning in an infinite iterative loop, the stack will not even be *growing* (much less overflowing) at all.

Comment: @NiklasB.: Good point - the last to sentences of the C++ memory model are not part of the C memory model. How odd :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your two programs are equivalent.  An example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f1(void)
{
    while(1)
        printf("Hi\n");
}

void f2(void)
{
loop:
    printf("Hi\n");
    goto loop;
}
```

Compile it:

```
cc -O3 -c -o example.o example.c
```

Look at the output binary:

```
example.o:
(__TEXT,__text) section
_f1:
0000000000000000    pushq   %rbp
0000000000000001    movq    %rsp, %rbp
0000000000000004    pushq   %rbx
0000000000000005    pushq   %rax
0000000000000006    leaq    L_str1(%rip), %rbx ## literal pool for: "Hi"
000000000000000d    nopl    _f1(%rax)
0000000000000010    movq    %rbx, %rdi
0000000000000013    callq   _puts
0000000000000018    jmp 0x10
000000000000001a    nopw    _f1(%rax,%rax)
_f2:
0000000000000020    pushq   %rbp
0000000000000021    movq    %rsp, %rbp
0000000000000024    pushq   %rbx
0000000000000025    pushq   %rax
0000000000000026    leaq    L_str1(%rip), %rbx ## literal pool for: "Hi"
000000000000002d    nopl    _f1(%rax)
0000000000000030    movq    %rbx, %rdi
0000000000000033    callq   _puts
0000000000000038    jmp 0x30
```

Note that they contain identical instructions.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `while(1)` will loop forever, or at least until you kill the process or your machine crashes. It's equivalent to the second program. It doesn't recurse, so there's no possibility of a stack overflow.